# Ajax returning correct data BUT at wrong place

Tags: ajax

I'm trying how to figure out how to use AJAX correctly with Wordpress: (I've used it on other sites, but not in WP)

I have this code in functions.php of a theme:

```
function jquery_stuff() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('scriptname', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/wibergsweb.js');
}
add_action( 'init', 'jquery_stuff');

//AJAX
add_action('wp_ajax_locationContent', 'locationContent');

function locationContent() {
    echo 'batman returns';
    die();
}
```

and this is what the jQuery looks like:

```
function loadLocationInfo(clickedOn) {   
        var locationId = clickedOn.next().attr('id');


        var locationContent = $.ajax({            
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                action: 'locationContent',
                location_id: locationId
            },
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        locationContent.done(function(data) {  
            alert('DONE');    
        });                        

        locationContent.fail(function(ts) {           
            alert('ERROR');
            clickedOn.next('.location-info').html(ts.responseText);
            $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            clickedOn.css('cursor', 'pointer');
       });
    } 

    $(document).on('click', 'h3', function(e) {
        var tClicked = $(this);
        loadLocationInfo(tClicked);
    });
```

Why is the actual response returned in the `fail`-function? (Yes, the data is correctly returned. That's the weird part of it).

This is what happens:

```
1. ERROR is shown in alert-dialog. 
2. The .location-info div is set to 'batman returns'
```

If I don't have die() in the php like this:

```
function locationContent() {
    echo 'batman returns';    
}
```

Then a **0** is returned **BUT** that 0 is returned in the `done()`-function (incorrect data returned at expected place)

Why is the actual response returned in the **fail-function** and how do I solve this issue? (I can't figure out what's going on here)

Comment: Is this front-end or back-end?

Comment: back-end . admin-use only

Comment: Well there goes my theory that maybe you needed to be using `wp_ajax_nopriv_`. On occasion, I have had to go into admin-ajax.php and change the `die()` messages to give me more of a clue as to where they are failing. Don't forget to undo your changes though as that caused me a major headache once.

Comment: I just tried that, but still the same issue (in case it was som weird things going on with authentification)

Comment: Check tutorial for Wordpress: loading more posts via AJAX. Here is the link: https://github.com/tokmak/wp-load-more-ajax

Comment: @tokmak - I'm not loading any actual posts, just some data from html-elements (not a form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the data type returned from the AJAX call to be JSON. However, the string you're returning ("batman begins") is not in JSON-format. Thus, the jQuery ajax-call will fail. Try passing your data as JSON using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
function locationContent() {
    echo json_encode( 'batman returns' );
    die();
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Furthermore, I can advise you to prefix your functions and adhere to the [WordPress PHP Coding Standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/) (`myplugin_locationcontent` instead of `locationContent`, for example).

Comment: YES, thank you. It was as simple as that!!! :-) I thought the ajax-hooks were handling this automatically because some tutorials I have read did just put echo 'string' and did not do any json-encoding on the serverside. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I actually used json_encode in my first attempt, but then I didn't have die() in the end of the ajax-function... therefore the confusion.